# how to use gsub function awk to replace characters with empty value

Tags: awk

for example my value alpha_1_2_u_345_cd.csv then i want to remove the characters present in using gsub in awk
output should be 
12345,alpha_1_2_u_345_cd.csv
please let me know if there any evaluation to be done

Please find the execution below

[image]

Comment: You mean like this? `awk '{gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"")}1' <<< 'alpha_1_2_u_345_cd.csv'`

Comment: could you let me know why is 1 used at the last is there any importance of the number,I'm a newbie to awk could you please elaborate @manatwork

Comment: “An AWK program consists of a sequence of pattern-action statements and optional function definitions.” “A missing action is equivalent to `{ print }` which prints the entire record.” (Quotes from `awk` manual.) So I just provided an always true pattern, letting `awk` perform the default action. So my code could be `{gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"")} 1==1{print}`, `{gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"")} 1{print}`, `{gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"")} {print}` or `{gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,""); print}` as well.

Comment: awk -F ',' '{print gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"",$2)1,"|"$3"|"$4"|"$5}' /home/cloudera/Desktop/rt.txt if i use the command including the other columns the value printed is always 7 in my case @manatwork

Comment: “**gsub(_r_, _s_ [, _t_])** For each substring matching the regular expression _r_ in the string _t_, substitute the string _s_, and return the number of substitutions.” Either do it in 2 steps: `{gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"",$2); print $2"|"$3"|"$4"|"$5}` or use the GNU extension `gensub()` function which returns the modified value: `{print gensub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"","g",$2)"|"$3"|"$4"|"$5}`.

Comment: @manatwork hey last question if the number comes in line 1_2_3_345_r2.csv then 2 after r to be excluded could you help me on that

Comment: You mean the part after the “r” to always go away? That you can do with another substitution: `{sub(/r.*/,"",$2); gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"",$2); print $2"|"$3"|"$4"|"$5}`. Or the `gensub()` way: `{print gensub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"","g",gensub(/r.*/,"",1,$2))"|"$3"|"$4"|"$5}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81638/discussion-between-a-r-naresh-and-manatwork).

Comment: This works good @manatwork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted by @manatwork

`{sub(/r.*/,"",$2); gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"",$2); print $2"|"$3"|"$4"|"$5}.`

Or the gensub() way:

```
{print gensub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"","g",gensub(/r.*/,"",1,$2))"|"$3"|"$4"|"$5}
```